# Which comes 1st, the mold remediation or the re-application of drylock on old stone walls?

Tags: basement, mold

Basement: old stone walls, drylock painted 15 yrs ago.

Now some stained, moisture damage, air mold test indicates pro.mold remediation needed.

Moisture issue has been fixed, now the walls need to be redone.

Drylock? Paint? Pro #1 says clean, apply drylock, then treat mold (basement/duct work) so as not to cover up the mold product.

Pro #2 says treat mold/ducts, then paint with drylock.  Will mold be remediated even if covered up?

They both use the same mold product.

What are the pros and cons of the two approaches and what considerations suggest picking one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used drylock, but have had good results using kilz, which seems to be a similar substance. The paint itself kills mold. On stone, I would use the oil based kilz after a thorough cleaning with bleach. Before applying, heat the space long enough to assure that everything is very dry.

Kilz seals the mold from entering the room. It also penetrates brick, block, and maybe even a little into certain types of stone.

Regarding duct work, and anywhere else the mold may have parked itself, it's important to clean/replace anything showing mold before applying kilz, because doing any work on ducts after the application will stir up mold again.

Wear a mask!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is interesting, but hard to understand due to the lack of capital letters, and the mis-placed periods. Would you edit it to make it clearer? Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for respectfully asking me to do this, instead of voting me down for capitalization and period placement. I edited it, and will go forward with the more accepted 'proper' formatting in the future.

Comment: Whoa: that's a rare response. Usually first-time posters just never come back; sometimes they do, but gripe. It's rare that someone actually works to make their post better. Many thanks, and hope to keep hearing from you.